# Parse a list and Guid in json from angular to controller

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am trying to post both a list of strings and a Guid from some angularjs to my controller.
I have succesfully created a solution where I can post the list to the controller but I cant figure out how I add the guid ($scope.CategoryId).
I have tried many different setups but most of the times if I change anything it never reaches the method in the controller when I click the button.
All help is very appreciated!

**My view:**

```
<form>
  <textarea class="form-control auto-input-field" rows="10" cols="80" id="autoGenerateInputField" ng-model="fighterList" ng-list="/\n/" />
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="GenerateTournamentTree()" value="Generer kamptræ" />
</form>
```

**My angularj:**

```
$scope.GenerateTournamentTree = function(){
    var stringOfFighters = new Array();
    var categoryId = $scope.CategoryId;
    stringOfFighters = $scope.fighterList;
    var postData = { fighters: stringOfFighters };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Api/Match/GenerateTournamentTree",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(stringOfFighters),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
}
```

**My controller:**

```
    [Route("api/Match/GenerateTournamentTree")]
    public IHttpActionResult GenerateTournamentTree(List<String> fighters)
    {
        fighters.Shuffle();
        var nodeTree = InsertNode(new TreeNode(), fighters);
        var matches = new List<MatchRecord>();
        GenerateMatch(matches, nodeTree);
        foreach(var match in matches)
        {
            match.CategoryId = new Guid("425d750e-56bd-412c-8a48-38c2fbe5b24c");
            match.EventId = 18;
        }
        db.Matches.AddRange(matches);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {               
            throw;              
        }
        return Json(new { Result = fighters });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a model that the  GenerateTournamentTree method accepts as a parameter. The model will hold properties 'fighters' and 'categoryId' to be mapped with the passed data.

In your project where the controller is there should be a folder named 'Models'. Create a new class named `TournamentBindingModel` for example. The class should hold the properties that you expect -> fighters and categoryId

```
public class TournamentBindingModel
    {
        public List<string> Fighters { get; set; }

        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

After that you can change your controller method's signature to

```
public IHttpActionResult GenerateTournamentTree(TournamentBindingModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The model's properties should be mapped by the data that is passed from the request and you should be able to access them like `model.Fighters` and `model.CategoryId` (parse the categoryId string to guid).

Comment: I have to admit that I am pretty new at all this. Are you able to give an example please?

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. I have a much better idea of how to fix it now. :)